# Where should I place my CSS styles for individual views in Laravel project?

Tags: css, laravel

I am new to Laravel and was wondering where I should put each css files for my views.  I want to keep them separate and don't to have my styles in one file. Also, how would I be able to access them in those views?  I tried using 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('/css/style.css') }}" />` but nothing changed in my view.  The path where I have my file is  `storage/public/css/style.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your link is `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('/css/style.css') }}" />` change it to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />` and put your style sheet in `/public/css/style.css`

Comment: Thank you that worked I just saw the public folder, I thought I had to put it on the storage public path.  Would it be similar if I want to use images, would I put it on that file path? and would I call it the same and just use the path name?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/style.css")}}">
```

used this code,here asset link to your public folder and put your style sheet in `/public/css/style.css`